# Google Drive API - Upload local folder node.js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

please, I would like to upload local folder with all files and subdirectories to Google Drive (API) with Node.js.

Code uploads only part of the file and not complete file. (i.e. image has 74kB, uploaded file 64kB, part of image is missing)

```
const simpleUpload = async (filename, path, parent) => {
const drive = await getDrive();

var fileMetadata = {
    'name': filename,
};
console.log(parent);
const parentFolder = await searchFiles(parent);
if (parentFolder.length > 0) {
    fileMetadata.parents = [parentFolder.pop().id]
}

const fileMimeType = mime.getType(path)
console.log(fileMimeType)

const media = {
    mimeType: fileMimeType,
    body: fs.createReadStream(path)
};

drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
    }
});
```

}

And usage:

```
var generator = fileHelper.walk('archive')
    setTimeout(function () {
        const file = generator.next().value;
        const pathParts = file.split(path.sep)

        googleDrive.createFolder(pathParts[1], 'archive')
            .then(() => {
                googleDrive.createFolder(pathParts[2], pathParts[1])
                    .then(() => {
                        googleDrive.simpleUpload(pathParts[3], file, pathParts[2]).then(() => console.log('File uploaded'))
                    })
            })
    }, 5000)
```

Please, help.

Comment: In order to understand correctly your situation, can I ask you about ``part of image is missing``? 1. Is the uploaded file of 64kB a part of the original image file? Or the uploaded file is not image file, and that it HTML file? 2. If the size of original image file is less than 64kB, what result will you obtain?

Comment: 1. Yes, is part of original image (around 70%)

Comment: Issue is described more here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1470

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that your script worked fine. So although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, can I ask you about the following points? 1. If the size of original image file is less than 64kB, what result will you obtain? 2. If ``mimeType`` is removed from ``media`` (or from both ``resource`` and ``media``), what result will you obtain?